# Tabs styling android-viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

[image]

**What is wanted:**
As seen below the`"RECENT"` selection, the selection indication is shown by the `blue line`. For my application I also want something similar.

**What was tried:** 
Using the `ViewPageIndicator` I tried to achieve this sort of `lined indication` but failed. But the following was tried:

```
<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tabpage_background</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
    </style>
```

where tabpage_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tabpage_unfocused"/>
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tabpage_selected"/>

</selector>
```

tabpage_unfocused:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#494949" />
</shape>
```

tabpage_selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
    <solid android:color="#FB9400"/>
</shape>
```

As you can see the code implementation only gives me a different background on selection, not the lined indication wanted. Please help!

Comment: use fragments with tabs.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger what do you mean ?

Comment: try this smaples https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use the library project from following link

[link](http://jakewharton.com/viewpagerindicator/)

Here you will get library project and sample projects...Hope this will work for you...